# Storing derived class to the vector C++

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, vector

I have problem with storing child class object to the vector. I have parent class

```
class IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = false;
};
```

I have second class

```
class Character : public IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = true;
};
```

Now, I am trying to create new instance of Character and stroe it to the vector. I have vector defined as

```
std::vector<IngameObject*> objVector;
```

Code for creating Characters and stroring them is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
     int a = i*32;
     Character *c = new Character(this->holderTextures["texture"], sf::IntRect(a, a, 32, 32), sf::Vector2f(2*a, 10.f));
     std::cout << instanceof<Character>(c) << " TEST" <<std::endl;
     this->objVector.emplace_back( c );
     std::cout << instanceof<Character>(this->objVector.back()) << " TEST" <<std::endl;
}
```

In the first case, instance is Character. After emplace_back to the objVector is type of instance IngameObject and bool clickable is set to false. What I am doing wrong?

EDIT
Instanceof is defined as

```
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T*) {
   return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

Comment: What is `instanceof`?

Comment: Added to the post. :)

Comment: Also note that `Character` has _two_ variables named `clickable`, `Character::clickable` and `IngameObject::clickable`. The default constructor will set the former to `true` and the latter to `false`. If you try to access `foo->clickable` where `foo` is a `IngameObject*` pointer, it will only be looking at `IngameObject::clickable`. Rather than declaring a new member variable, write a `Character` constructor that correctly sets the value of the inherited variable.

Comment: `instanceof<Character>(this->objVector.back())` will always be `false`, regardless of whether `objVector.back()` happens to point to a `Character` or not. `objVector.back()` is an `IngameObject*`, meaning that you are checking `std::is_base_of<Character, IngameObject>::value` which is `false`. If you want to do a _runtime_ check of whether the actual pointed-to-object is an instance of `Character` you'll need to do a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Your `ingameObject` lacks a virtual destructor, thus is not safe to use in a polymorphic manner.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, I added virtual destructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a derived class in a `std::vector` as you do is correct: the problem is not related with polymorphism or "storing derived class in a vector":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = false;
};

class Character : public IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<IngameObject*> objVector;
    
    Character *c = new Character();
    objVector.emplace_back( c );
    
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is related with you you implement `instanceof`

---

To solve the `instanceof` function, your class need to be polymorphic. Then, the pointer to the base class can be converted to the derived class, thus confirming that it is `instanceof` the base class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = false;
    virtual ~IngameObject() = default;
};

class Character : public IngameObject
{
protected:
    bool clickable = true;
};

template<class T, class U>
inline bool instanceof(U* ptr) {
   return nullptr != dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<IngameObject*> objVector;
    
    Character *c = new Character();
    std::cout << instanceof<Character>(c) << " TEST" <<std::endl;
    objVector.emplace_back( c );
    std::cout << instanceof<Character>(objVector.back()) << " TEST" <<std::endl;
    
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: to make `Base` polymorphic, it needs to have at least one virtual method.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: It shows how to store a derived class in a vector. In the while, I am trying to solve it "instanceof" function.

Comment: In your `instanceof()`, the `Base` parameter is misleading since that is the *derived* type being tested for. I would use this instead: `template<class T, class U> inline bool instanceof(U* u) { return nullptr != dynamic_cast<T*>(u); }`

Comment: Fixed! I tried to change as little as possible his code, but I agree with your suggestion 100%.